# How to convert a character array to a decimal integer array?

Tags: c

I would like to convert a `character array` to a `decimal array`. For example, in the extended ASCII Table, lowercase q is 113. I would ask a prompt to get a text from the user and then the user might input "qqq", then input[] would be ['q','q','q'] and intinput[] would be ['113','113','113'].

Is there a way to do this? Thank you

```
char input[50], ch;
int intinput[50];
int j = 0, l = 0;

printf("Enter Cleartext: ");
while((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    input[j] = ch;  
    j++;
}

for(l = 0;input[l] != '\0'; l++) {
    intinput[l] = input[l] - '0';
}
```

the `"intinput[l] = input[l] - '0';"` does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop try

```
for(l =0; input[l]!= '\0'; l++)
{
    intinput[l] = (int)input[l];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you most of the way there if you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do.  Your example doesn't seem to indicate you want to create integers like

['0', '0', '0'] going to [0, 0, 0], so I didn't do any subtraction.  Your example indicates a direct ascii conversion.

Here is the answer that gives me [113, 113, 113, 0, 0, 0, 0..0] by using the code you provided:

```
char input[50] = { 0 }, ch;
int intinput[50] = { '\0' };
int j = 0, l = 0;



printf("Enter Cleartext: ");
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
    input[j] = ch;
    j++;
}

for (l = 0; input[l] != '\0'; l++) {
    intinput[l] = (int)input[l];
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it does work, although there could be a better answer

Answer (score 0):

When you store ASCII chars in a variable they are stored as it's ASCII value. So you don't need to do a mapping. Reverse is same too. That is you can cast an int to char. Then first 8 byte will be copied to char due to sizes are different in these two types and when you print it'll show the character responding to that value of the byte.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to typecast for this, simply assignment would do fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{

    char char_arr[50] = {[0 ... 49] = '\0'};
    int  int_arr[50] = {[0 ... 49] = 0};
    int  count=0;
    int  input;
    int  loop_var=0;

    while((input=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        if(input == '\n')
            break;

        char_arr[count] = input;
        int_arr[count] = input;
        ++count;
    }

    while(loop_var<count)
    {
        printf("Character: %c Corresponding Integer: %d\n",char_arr[loop_var],int_arr[loop_var] );
        loop_var++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**INPUT:** `qqq`

**OUTPUT:**

```
Character: q Corresponding Integer: 113
Character: q Corresponding Integer: 113
Character: q Corresponding Integer: 113
```